# Angular package ng2-table: what does this code statement mean?

Tags: angular, typescript

Can someone tell me what this code statement means?

`this.rows = page && config.paging ? this.changePage(page, sortedData) : sortedData;`

Comment: It's checking whether you have paging enabled (or more directly, whether page and config.paging are defined). If so, set rows to be the current page of the sorted data, otherwise just the entire sorted data set. If you don't know what the ? and : represent, look up ternary operator.

Comment: so it is a ternary operation? Ok thanks

Answer (score 0):

If there is a **page** AND **config** has a **paging** property, make **this.rows** equal the result of **this.changePage(page.sortedData)**, otherwise, make **this.rows** equal **sortedData**.